# Create table form JSON

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

I am trying to create a table from JSON. And I think I have a problem with my link but not also. No data appears on my table. My error are :

> Cannot read property 'symbol' of undefined
> 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'symbol' of undefined
> at Object. (main.js:14)
> at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
> at Object.success (main.js:11)
> at u (jquery.min.js:2)
> at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
> at k (jquery.min.js:2)
> at XMLHttpRequest.'

Here is my JS Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json", function(json) {

    enter code here

    var currentprice = '';
    $.each(json.bpi, function(key, value) {
      var USD = value.USD
      currentprice += '<tr>';
      currentprice += '<td>' + USD.symbol + '</td>';
      currentprice += '<td>' + USD.description + '</td>';
      currentprice += '<td>' + USD.rate + '</td>';
     
      currentprice += '</tr>';
    });
    $("#current_table").append(currentprice);
  })
})
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check if the value exists and set to an empty string if the value does not exist.

```
var currentprice = '';
$.each(json.bpi, function(key, value) {
var USD = value.USD
var symbol = USD.symbol || ""
var description = USD.description || ""
var rate = USD.rate || ""
+= '<tr>';
+= '<td>' + symbol + '</td>';
+= '<td>' + description + '</td>';
+= '<td>' + rate + '</td>';

+= '</tr>';
});
$("#current_table").append(currentprice);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looping through `json.bpi` which will give you `USD,GBP..etc` so just use `value.keyname` to get particular values from json object.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json", function(json) {
    var currentprice = '';
    $.each(json.bpi, function(key, value) {
      currentprice += '<tr>';
      currentprice += '<td>' + value.symbol + '</td>';
      currentprice += '<td>' + value.description + '</td>';
      currentprice += '<td>' + value.rate + '</td>';

      currentprice += '</tr>';
    });
    $("#current_table").append(currentprice);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="current_table" border='1'>
</table>
```